# How do I find out in the OpenCV C Inerface,...In what .so a OpenCV function is defined

Tags: c, opencv, cffi

Like for example if I was trying to call cvNamedWindow....what .so would the cvNamedWindow information be in.....Please give me the info so I can track this info down myself for any C OpenCV function...I usually grep my opencv 2.4.6 folder which includes these folders 3rdparty  apps  build  cmake  CMakeLists.txt  data  doc  include  index.rst  modules  platforms  README  samples so I'm used to searching like that if you tell where to look...
My knowledge so far...there is a CV_IMPL for cvNamedWindow in the highgui folder modules/highgui/src/  so I think it comes from there but repeating the same for cvmGet doesn't return a CV_IMPL.....I'm trying to wrap cvmGet and I'm getting an undefined alien function error...but I'm including:

```
(cffi:define-foreign-library calib3d
    (:unix "/usr/local/lib/libopencv_calib3d.so.2.4.6" ))
(cffi:use-foreign-library calib3d)

(cffi:define-foreign-library legacy
    (:unix "/usr/local/lib/libopencv_legacy.so.2.4.6" ))
(cffi:use-foreign-library legacy)
```

where I think cvmGet is plus all other opencv .so files

this is for Lisp on Ubuntu 13.10,  OpenCV 2.4.6

Comment: To find where is function put into, check opencv reference http://docs.opencv.org/modules/refman.html

Answer (score 1):

You need to look into http://docs.opencv.org.

If you were to try and locate the `Sobel` function for instance, you would see that the documentation path is (at the top of the webpage `OpenCV 2.4.6.0 documentation » OpenCV API Reference » imgproc. Image Processing`)
So the corresponding module is `imgproc`.

You can use this to locate into which module your functions are